# Ternary operator in PHP generated table

Tags: php, html, ternary-operator

I have a PHP generated table that simply compares two order numbers and outputs a simple pass or fail if they match or do not. Based on the result i am trying to get the table to set the background colour of the row to be either green or red (visual identification).

to keep it simple i am trying to use a ternary operator but the row colour only comes out as the first argument (green), and the fails do not appear red.

Table Code:

```
while ($add_info = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getres)){


    $row = ($add_info['row']);
    $worksorder = ($add_info['id']);
    $scanned = ($add_info['scanned']);
    $result = ($add_info['result']);


echo ("<tr  ($result == 'PASS') ? style='background-color:green' : style='background-color:red'> <td/> $row    <td/> $worksorder  <td/> $scanned   <td/> $result 
</tr>");
```

The operator section in particular:

```
<tr  ($result == PASS) ? style='background-color:green' : style='background-color:red'>
```

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tzw4.jpg)

This seems like it should be straight forward, i'm just missing something fundamental.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still within quotes which is going to cause PHP to echo everything. What you meant to do was:

```
echo "<tr ";
echo $result == 'PASS' ? "style='background-color:green'>" : "style='background-color:red'>";
echo "<td/> $row    <td/> $worksorder  <td/> $scanned   <td/> $result";
echo "</tr>";
```

Also, I don't believe those self-closing `<td/>` tags are valid... I'd suggest using the full `<td>cell contents</td>` format.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! your code solves the issue of the pass/fail, and i can see the reasoning.However if the response is pass, the table is shifting one to left (the row number is now outside the table), however a fail will display in the correct columns. any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Appears I was missing a closing `>`